# stop timeouts server side?

Tags: c#, timeout, tcplistener

In my client I have done:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
client.SendTimeout = 1000;
```

I also get marks for doing it server side, I tried checking with intellisense on my TCPListener in my server, but I cant find anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: What timeouts would you expect to find on `TCPListener`? It is a factory object and could care less about your communication timeouts.

Comment: How do I handle timeouts server side then, I'm guessing its not as simple asthe client side stuff?

Comment: @Lewis - It certainly is as easy, it's identical. I'll post an answer

Answer (score 3):

On the server side, you're using [`TcpListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) which is nothing more than a [`Socket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) or [`TcpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) factory.

Somewhere in the server code you'll see either `AcceptTcpClient` or `AcceptSocket` (or their async counterparts). Something like:

```
TcpClient clientConn = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
```

Now you have the equivalent of `client` from the code snippet in your question. So to set the timeouts:

```
clientConn.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
clientConn.SendTimeout = 1000;
```

You can do something similar with `Socket` instances if that is what it uses (I can dig up some code if this is the case), but in general it is pretty much the same.

**UPDATE**

Since on the server side you're using `AcceptSocket` rather than `AcceptTcpClient`, you can use the following:

```
Socket clientConn = listener.AcceptSocket();
clientConn.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
clientConn.SendTimeout = 1000;
```

It's basically identical, just using a different type for `clientConn`.

Comment: Thanks for this I'm using socket instances I think :

connection = listener.AcceptSocket();
socketStream = new NetworkStream(connection);

How do I set timeouts with these?

Comment: [Socket.ReceiveTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivetimeout.aspx) and [Socket.SendTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.sendtimeout.aspx)

Comment: No, `connection.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;`

Comment: Thanks, what would you recommend as appropriate values for these?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do with them. I assume based on your question that you never want the server side to timeout, so no timeout at all would be indicated using a -1.